# Can frama-c be used for header file analysis?

Tags: ocaml, frama-c

I was looking at frama-c as a way to process C header files in OCaml (e.g. for generating language bindings). It's attractive because it seems like a very well-documented and maintained project. However, after a lot of googling and searching through the documentation, I can't find anything suitable for the purpose. Am I just missing the right way to do this, or is it outside the scope of frama-c? It seems like a fairly trivial thing for it to do, compared to some of the other plugins.

Comment: This may be cilly suggestion as I'm not sure of what it does exactly, but could maybe [CIL](http://kerneis.github.com/cil/) help you ?

Comment: thanks for the pointer - will poke through the cil documentation and see if it has anything helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Pascal said, I don't think that it is possible from the command line, but because you will have to write some code anyway, you can set the flag `Rmtmps.keepUnused`. This is a script that you can use to see the declarations :

```
let main () =
  Rmtmps.keepUnused := true;
  let file = File.from_filename "t.h" in
  let () = File.init_from_c_files [ file ] in
  let _ast = Ast.get () in
  let show_function f =
    let name = Kernel_function.get_name f in
    if not (Cil.Builtin_functions.mem name) then
      Format.printf "Function @[<2>%a:@ @[@[type: %a@]@ @[%s at %a@]@]@]@."
        Kernel_function.pretty f
        Cil_datatype.Typ.pretty (Kernel_function.get_type f)
        (if Kernel_function.is_definition f then "defined" else "declared")
        Cil.d_loc (Kernel_function.get_location f)
in Globals.Functions.iter show_function

let () = Db.Main.extend main
```

To run it, you have to use the `-load-script` option like this :

```
$ frama-c -load-script script.ml
```

Developing a plug-in will be more appropriate for more complex processing (see the *Developer Manual* for that), but a script make it easy to test.

Answer (score 1):

In the current state, I would say that it is unfortunately impossible to use Frama-C to parse declarations of functions that are neither defined or used.

t.h:

```
int mybinding (int x, int y);
```

This gives you a view of the normalized AST. Normalized means that everything that could be simplified was:

```
$ frama-c -print t.h
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  t.h"
/* Generated by Frama-C */
```

And unfortunately, since `mybinding` was neither used nor defined, it was erased.

There is an option to keep declarations with specifications, but what you want is an option to keep all declarations. I have never noticed such an option:

```
$ frama-c -kernel-help
...
-keep-unused-specified-functions  keep specified-but-unused functions (set by
                    default, opposite option is
                    -remove-unused-specified-functions)
```

And the option to keep functions with specifications does not do what you want:

```
$ frama-c -keep-unused-specified-functions -print t.h
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  t.h"
/* Generated by Frama-C */
```